# How to assign background image to html div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone explain this to me:

I have a div which background image is working:

```
<section class="bottom-banner" id="imagebannerthree" style="background-image:url(https://*****.com.au/wp-content/custom-products/1628/bottom-3.jpg);">
</section>
```

but when i tried loading background image using javascript there is no image loaded:

```
document.getElementById('imagebannerthree').style.backgroundImage = checkImage("https://*****.com.au/wp-content/custom-products/1628/bottom-3.jpg");

 function checkImage(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();

    if (http.status == 200) {
        return 'url(' + url + ')';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('' + parentdiv).remove();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you describe what checkImage is to do? It seems that if the image doesn't load then you want to remove the parent element, but then you return to the assignment which has an element which now no longer exists (I am guessing at the HTML structure here).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use quotes while assigning value to style.backgroudImage

```
document.getElementById('imagebannerthree').style.backgroundImage = "url('https://*****.com.au/wp-content/custom-products/1628/bottom-3.jpg')";
```

you most probably getting the error "url is not a function".

Comment: Still not loading image. I will edit my question

Comment: It seems to be working for me, check for console errors if any.

Comment: and I believe you are using element id correctly!

Comment: I have CORS error even after allowing CORS in my php server. please see my updated question.

Comment: the question is now more related to PHP instead of js/html/css. I wonder why you are getting cors error. Is not you image served from same origin.

Comment: I haven't grasped the point of this answer as the code given in the question attempts to wrap the url in a string with url(...) in the JS function so the extra quotes arent needed. They are needed in the assignment structure shown in this answer, but that isn't the same as in the question.

Comment: @A Haworth, the question is being edited after the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('imagebanner').style.backgroundImage = "url(https://piranhatc.com.au/wp-content/custom-products/1628/bottom-3.jpg)";

 function checkImage(url) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', url, false);
    http.send();

    if (http.status == 200) {
        return 'url(' + url + ')';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('' + parentdiv).remove();
    }
  }
```

```css
.bottom-banner {
  object-fit: cover; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<section class="bottom-banner" id="imagebanner">
</section>
```

name in id does not match.
The functions written below seem irrelevant.

Comment: I updated my question, you read it first

Comment: @jreloz You need to show the url to the image you are trying to load, that way anyone providing answer has more context

Comment: It looks as though the function is trying to delete some element(s) if the background image load is not successful so possibly not irrelevant.

Comment: @AHaworth you dont get the code do you?